# How to display and save mutiple instances of a django form based on variable amount?

Tags: python, django, forms

I've been looking around the site and can't seem to find an answer. Same for the django docs. The issue is I can't seem to save multiple instances of the same form. 
I'm trying to have a user set up a weekly calendar for a sports club. They land on a page with check boxes of each day they have activities. So if they click monday, tuesday, wednesday. Three instances of the DAY model are created created. Which works fine.

Then, on the next page. Based on the amount of Days they have chosen, I would like a PeriodsForm (for this example let's just say they have one period each day). Then they can set what time each day starts and finises.

I just can't seem to save the data. I was hoping someone has come across this before.

Many thanks.

I've tried using the modelformset_factory() but it's far too rigid. I also tried prefixes but I can't seem to loop through the forms on the POST.

```py
### views.py

def create_timetable_days(request):
    club = request.user.club
    form = TimetableCreateForm(request.POST or None)
    if len(list(Day.objects.filter(club=club))) > 0:
        return redirect('/timetables/create_timetable_times')
    if form.is_valid():
        for item in form['Days']:
            if item.data['selected']:
                day = Day(name=item.data['label'], club=club)
                day.save()
        return redirect('/timetables/create_timetable_times')
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'timetables/create_timetable_days.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def create_timetable_times(request):
    club = request.user.club
    days = Day.objects.filter(club=club)

#### Lost a bit around here

    form = PeriodCreateForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        for k in form:
            start_time = k.cleaned_data['start_time']
            end_time = k.cleaned_data['end_time']
            period = Periods(start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time)
            period.save()

        return redirect('/')


    context = {
        'forms': forms,
        'days': days,
    }
    return render(request, 'timetables/create_timetable_times.html', context)

### models.py 

class Day(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, verbose_name=Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Periods(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day, verbose_name=Day, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

#### timetable.py

DAYS = (
    (1, "Monday"),
    (2, "Tuesday"),
    (3, "Wednesday"),
    (4, "Thursday"),
    (5, "Friday"),
    (6, "Saturday"),
    (7, "Sunday"),
)
HOURS = (('00', '00'), ('05', '05'), ('10', '10'), ('15', '15'), ('20', '20'))


class TimetableCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Days = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=DAYS, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = Day
        fields = ['Days']


class PeriodCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_time = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                                   choices=HOURS, )
    end_time = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
        choices=HOURS,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Periods
        fields = ['start_time', 'end_time']
```

Comment: Formsets are exactly what you want. Why are they "too rigid"? Where did you run into problems?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to give each form a title referring it's day. Also on the POST I couldn't pull out the correct data I wanted. I was going down this road which felt wrong. `PeriodFormSet = modelformset_factory(Periods, form=PeriodCreateForm, extra=0 if len(Periods.objects.all()) > 0 else len(Day.objects.all()))` I think I should give the formset another go